# コンパイル エラーです。: プロシージャの外では無効です。どこのエラーを修正すればよいのでしょうか？

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).SlideShowTransition
    .Speed = ppTransitionSpeedFast
    .EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
    .SoundEffect.ImportFromFile "c:\sndsys\bass.wav"
    .AdvanceOnTime = True
    .AdvanceTime = 5
End With

ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = _
ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings
    
Next sld

With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).SlideShowTransition
    .Speed = ppTransitionSpeedFast
    .EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
    .SoundEffect.ImportFromFile "c:\sndsys\bass.wav"
    .AdvanceOnTime = True
    .AdvanceTime = 10
End With

ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = _
ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings

Next sld

With ActivePresentation.Slides(3).SlideShowTransition
    .Speed = ppTransitionSpeedFast
    .EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
    .SoundEffect.ImportFromFile "c:\sndsys\bass.wav"
    .AdvanceOnTime = True
    .AdvanceTime = 92
End With

ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = _
ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings
    
End Sub
Sub 画面切り替え時間()

End Sub
```

Comment: 単に`Sub`~`End Sub`の間に入っていないのでは？ [マクロ処理はプロシージャの外では無効だから中に入れてあげようね](https://www.wantedly.com/companies/avinton/post_articles/38193), [VBAのプロシージャとは](https://www.vba-ie.net/programing/procedure.php), [プロシージャの外では無効です](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-outside-procedure) それからソースコードだけ提示されても適切な助言・回答は難しいですね。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に詳細な情報を追記してください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

1. プロシージャの中に記述します。

プログラム特有の言い回しで、戻り値のない関数(=ひとまとまりの処理)のことをプロシージャ(procedure: 手続き)と呼ぶことがあります。
また紛らわしいのですが、VBAではプロシージャのことを`Sub 画面切り替え時間()`のように`Sub`(Sub routineの略)から始まり`End Sub`で終わるひとまとまりの処理として表現します。
なので特定の処理を実行するにはプロシージャの中に記述することが通例です。
(`Option Explicit`による宣言部などの例外もありますが、ややこしいので割愛します)

今回コンパイルエラーが発生する原因は、コメントにある通り下記のコードで「`Sub`がないのに`End Sub`がある」ことと「`Sub 画面切り替え時間()`の中に何も記述されていない」ことがエラーの原因ではないでしょうか。

```
End Sub  '対応するSubがないのにEnd Subがある
Sub 画面切り替え時間()
  '中に何もいませんよ
End Sub
```

2. Next sldは不要です。

前回のご質問のサンプルコードを流用されたことと思いますが、`sld`はSlide型として宣言(Dimension)された変数です。
下記のように`For Each`文で`sld`にスライドの各ページを代入して次のページに遷移する`For Each xxx ～ Next xxx`の構文で表されるひとまとまりの処理は有効です。

```
　Dim sld As Slide

　For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    ' なにがしかの処理
  Next sld
```

しかし`For Each`がないのに`Next sld`があると、「`Sub`がないのに`End Sub`がある」場合と同様にエラーとなります。

上記2点をふまえて下記のコードに書き換えるとコンパイルエラーを解消することができました。

```
Sub 画面切り替え時間()
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).SlideShowTransition
        .Speed = ppTransitionSpeedFast
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
        .SoundEffect.ImportFromFile "c:\sndsys\bass.wav" 
        .AdvanceOnTime = True
        .AdvanceTime = 5
    End With

    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = _
    ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).SlideShowTransition
        .Speed = ppTransitionSpeedFast
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
        .SoundEffect.ImportFromFile "c:\sndsys\bass.wav" 
        .AdvanceOnTime = True
        .AdvanceTime = 10
    End With

    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = _
    ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(3).SlideShowTransition
        .Speed = ppTransitionSpeedFast
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
        .SoundEffect.ImportFromFile "c:\sndsys\bass.wav" 
        .AdvanceOnTime = True
        .AdvanceTime = 92
    End With

    ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = _
    ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings

    'おまけ
    Call 引数で画面切り替え(4, 6)
    Call 引数で画面切り替え(5, 11)
    Call 引数で画面切り替え(6, 93)
End Sub

Sub 引数で画面切り替え(PageNo As Integer, AdvanceTime As Integer)
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(PageNo).SlideShowTransition
        .Speed = ppTransitionSpeedFast
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
        .SoundEffect.ImportFromFile "c:\sndsys\bass.wav" 
        .AdvanceOnTime = True
        .AdvanceTime = AdvanceTime
    End With
End Sub
```

なお、おまけのように`Sub`関数は任意の場所から引数付きで呼び出すことができます。
サンプルコードの 'おまけでは4ページ目から6ページ目にかけて6秒,11秒,93秒で画面切り替えのタイミングを指定しています。

Comment: 早速のご回答、ありがとうございました。サンプルコードもつけて頂きほんとうにありがとうございました。これからも、ご指導を頂き勉強させて頂きたいと思います！